# Avoid Magento 2 from automatically adding tax rate to uploaded gross prices

Tags: magento2, tax, tax-class, tax-calculation, order-totals

I upload my prices as gross prices incl. all taxes.

Still I want the invoice to show the tax rate without Magento adding it automatically during checkout.
I need Magento to understand my product prices as gross prices, not as net prices. Same applies for shipping prices.

**Example:**

product price: 10

tax rate: 10%

Magento total: 11

**What I need:**

product price: 10

tax rate: 10%

Magento total: 10

(invoice showing: product price: 9.09, tax rate: 10%, total price: 10)

Basically as it is in any other shop. Shown are the gross prices that include tax but the invoice shows the net price + tax which then is the total price (the one I uploaded for the product).

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked tax settings

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/tax/tax-settings-general.html

> To configure the general tax settings:
>
> On the Admin sidebar, go to Stores > Settings > Configuration.
>
> For a multisite configuration, set Store View to the website and store that is the target of the configuration.
>
> Complete the following configuration settings. If necessary, clear the Use System value checkbox of any settings that are grayed out.

You want

> Catalog Prices — Set to Excluding Tax or Including Tax

Set `Including Tax`

Then you may have to tweak the display settings

Although if you are storing products including tax you will have to consider the prices when shipping to a tax free destination.

Comment: It's going to be trial and error until you get the exact settings you need.

Comment: I tried that before. What Magento does here, is to add the set tax rate to the catalog prices. So sticking to my example instead of price 10 it shows 11.
It's a stupid system, I don't understand why I can't set Magento to show my uploaded prices as gross prices and then calculates the tax as a part of my gross prices.